# Frame and Bounds of CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, cgpath, cashapelayer

I am working on `CAShapeLayer`.And trying to draw non-linear path.I want to set frame to `CAShapeLayer`.So i can use `CGPathGetPathBoundingBox` method to get frame from `CGPathRef`.

**Here is code :**

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2, 100, (0), (M_PI_2), NO);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2, 100-50, (M_PI_2), (0), YES);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
CAShapeLayer* arcLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc]init];
arcLayer.path = path;
arcLayer.frame = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path);
arcLayer.bounds = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path);
[self.layer addSublayer:arcLayer]; `
```

Please refer my code carefully .I have set same frame and bounds to CAShapeLayer.My problem is if i am not setting bounds (same as frame) ,then it wont show my content or it wont show my content within frame.Why?Please help me.Thanking you.

Answer (score 17):

When you modify the `frame` of a `CALayer`, you are modifying its size and position in the coordinate space of its superlayer. `frame` is a computed value, based on the object's `bounds` and `position`. In this case, the layer does not yet have a superlayer so its coordinate space is dimensionless. When you set the `frame`, the size gets carried through to the `bounds` property, but since any point in a dimensionless space is zero, the position will remain zero instead of what you'd intended.

To solve this, you can set the `bounds` to set the layer's size, and `position` (which is a real non-computed property) in the coordinate space of the superlayer before adding it as a sublayer.

Answer (score 11):

The following is a quote from the `CALayer` documentation:

> The frame rectangle is position and size of the layer specified in the superlayer’s coordinate space. For layers, the frame rectangle is a computed property that is derived from the values in the bounds, anchorPoint and position properties. When you assign a new value to this property, the layer changes its position and bounds properties to match the rectangle you specified. The values of each coordinate in the rectangle are measured in points.

It looks like with the CAShapeLayer when setting the `frame` by itself it does't keep the origin values from the assigned CGRect, only the size. When you set the `bounds` the origin is kept and therefore displays in the proper location. You also need to set the position value to the center point of where you want you shape to be displayed:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2, 100, (0), (M_PI_2), NO);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2, 100-50, (M_PI_2), (0), YES);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
CAShapeLayer* arcLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
arcLayer.path = path;
CGRect pathRect = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path);
arcLayer.bounds = pathRect;
arcLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(pathRect), CGRectGetMidY(pathRect));
[self.layer addSublayer:arcLayer];
```

Comment: So, in a sentence: Don't set `frame`, just `bounds`, and also set `position`?

Comment: Yes. Although, I thought that a 500 point question required a slightly more verbose response.

Comment: In general with layers I think you get the best results by setting _bounds_ + _position_ and not _frame_. But for CAShapeLayer, I don't think bounds is important, unless you want to add a translation to the contents. However this doesn't explain why the path isn't being drawn does it?

Comment: I guess the drawing is being done outside the bounds of the enclosing view/layer and one of those has [clips|masks]toBounds = YES.. (just a guess though)

Comment: Thanks with a few change it worked, we almost invested a day in this, thanxx a lot

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, setting the `position` of a `CAShapeLayer` is completely sufficient for it to show up where you want it. Setting the `bounds` is not required for this.

See the [CoreAnimationText](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreAnimationText/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code for using it that way.

Comment: That depends on what you're doing with the layer later. If you try to transform it with empty `bounds`, results may be hilarious.

Comment: Interesting. I have done a lot of transformations of `CAShapeLayer`  objects grouped as sublayers of another `CALayer`. Luckily, I never had issues. Will keep that in mind, if hilarity should ensue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `bounds` or else it will behave like the `anchorPoint` is set to `[0, 0]`. Who wants that? :D