# Set TopLeft & bottomLeft radius of a UIButton | iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uibutton

I want to set the **Top/Bottom Left** corner radius of UIButton. How can i achieve this?

If i use `button.layer.cornerRadius`, it'll set all the corners.

I've tried using *UIBazierPath*, but probably i'm doing something wrong and the button is not appearing correctly. The code i've used is:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: button.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 3.0, height: 3.0))

let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = path.CGPath
button.layer.mask = mask
```

I've tried the answers from stackoverflow i.e [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview) but it's not working for me. It's updating the corners but reducing button's height as well. I think i'm doing something wrong with frame/bounds.

Using above code, the UIButton appears as:

[image: .]

Another solution i used was to use the image with rounded corners. but now i want to do this programmatically.

Thanks.

Comment: whats the result of the above code ?

Comment: I've updated the question @Mr.T

Comment: The button corners seemed to be rounded. What is the issue then ?

Comment: I think corners are updated correctly, but there's some issue with frame/bounds. Can you spot that?

Comment: you mean the arrow mark which is shifted down ?

Comment: yes, basically the height of button is reduced.

Comment: Image updated again @Mr.T

Comment: set `CAShapeLayer`'s bounds and position to your buttons bounds and center respectively. I guess it will fix the problem.

Comment: @meth, can u kindly explain what you're saying! i didn't really get it. Should n't it work as i'm setting the bounds for bazirePath and then setting path of     CAShapeLayer
if you're saying something like: mask.bounds = button.bounds, then i've tried this one, and it reduce the button's height to 1/4

Comment: yes i was talking about that. [in this questions answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955210/frame-and-bounds-of-cashapelayer) there are more detailed explanations that may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did your layout change? For instance, if you place the code in `viewDidLoad` of a `UIViewController` and the view gets resized by autolayout, then this could happen. If you move the code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` then it should work.

Comment: Writing in ViewDidLayoutSubviews fixed the issue. Thankyou :) @uchiha

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this in objective C by using the following method:

```
-(void)setMaskTo:(UIView*)view byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners
{
    UIBezierPath* rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds
                                              byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                   cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0, 8.0)];   
    CAShapeLayer* shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];
    view.layer.mask = shape;
}
```

Call the above method this way:

```
[self setMaskTo:self.myButton byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerTopLeft];
```

Comment: i've added the image. I'm doing the samething as yours in swift. But something is wrong and i am unable to figure that out. @R3D3vil

Comment: are you using stackviews? I have issues rounding buttons when they are part of a stackview.

Comment: no i'm not using stackviews but autolayouts @R3D3vil